# Find Current through RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog

So i found some practice RLC,RL,RC questions online and one of them asks you to find the voltage across the capacitor/impedance/capacitive reactance and the current through the capacitor at 1kHz but i have absolutely no clue how to find it ,if you could pls explain **simple** as possible or give the formula on finding it ,it would be great

RC series Circuit

Resistor - 100 Ohms

Capacitor - 0.01uF

Voltage source -10v A.C

at 1kHz

[image]

My calculations

Comment: But you already have found the current through the capacitor **Irms = 0.00062A = 620µA** . Also, notice that **15 951Ω** is no equal to  **160Ω** but **15.951kΩ ≈ 16kΩ** instead.

Comment: @G36 would i just do the same thing if i wanted to find the current through the inductor ? .10v/impedance ?

Comment: In a series circuit, yes. Because in a series circuit only one current is flowing.

Comment: @G36 OO ok i see ok , Thank you very much